# Fast way to check existence of host

Tags: c#

In C#:

If I ping a url (eg. "http://myurl.com") and that url doesn't exist I get a SocketException (No such host is know). This request is a very fast way to determine if a address exist. Is there any similar way to check if an IP "exists"?

Obviously there is the possibility to ping the IP, but if the host is located in china (and I'm located in Sweden) then the ping time gets very long...

Comment: What do you mean by 'exist' here?

Comment: also some hosts are configured to not respond to ping

Comment: If you can not ping a host it must not be true that the host is not reachable.

Comment: Catch a UnknownHostException is the best way through java.net.

Comment: sorry i thought you wanted java way to do it. just now I knew you are looking for C# codes. I have no idea in C#. Read this post -http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/109427/How-to-PING-Server-in-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no foolproof way to check if an IP is used since the use is not registered anywhere.

The reason the hostname check is fast is that you don't need to actually talk to the host to figure out whether the hostname exists, it's registered in the DNS system.

The hostname check you're doing in no way guarantees that the *host* actually exists, just that an alias from the hostname to an IP number exists, the host may well be down and you won't know from that lookup.

Also, even if you use ping to try to figure out if an IP is used, you're not sure since there may be a firewall blocking ping and still letting other IP traffic through (HTTP for example). To best know if a host available to serve your requests, you're best off polling it using the actual protocol you're interested in.

Answer (score 6):

IT's not entirely clear what you mean. You could perform DNS resolution with [`Dns.GetHostEntry(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998.aspx) which will resolve a name (such as "myurl.com") to a host entry (potentially many addresses)- but that won't tell you if anything is actually using those IP addresses.

What are you trying to accomplish? Usually if you want to find out whether a particular host exists, it's because you want to talk to it using a specific protocol (e.g. HTTP). In that case it's better to make a request *with that protocol* - otherwise even if the host exists, there's nothing to say it's useful to you.

Comment: Sometimes it takes 5-6 seconds to check if the host exists. And I stopped checking at all after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try telnet. http://dotnettelnet.sourceforge.net/

Once connected you're sure you reached your IP and then immediately issue a close session. Otherwise, the ip is unreachable.