# I keep getting an exception when Ping can't reach a host name C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write something that picks up an input in a text box, then appends it with a prefix, then pings the two. Every time I run the script, if it cannot find the host name it gives me an exception. Is there any way I can force past the exception so that it goes onto the else statement? Or is there something simple that I'm missing?

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter an asset tag number.", "Dramatic failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
    else
    {
        string assetTag = textBox1.Text;

        Ping pingSender = new Ping();

        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        int timeout = 1000;

        PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);

        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send("WES0" + assetTag);

        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The IP address is: ", "Great sucess!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what's the exception?  You can catch and handle exceptions with a `try/catch` block.

Comment: Read [ask]. Being new and all, it helps to actually get familiar with the site you're posting on...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800748/fast-way-to-check-existence-of-host

Answer (score 1):

Catch the exeption with `try / catch`. Something like:

```
try
{
    PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(nameOrAddress);

    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The IP address is: ", "Great sucess!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
catch (PingException)
{
    // Discard PingExceptions
}
```

> The Ping class throws this exception to indicate that while sending an
>   Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) Echo request, a method called
>   by the Ping class threw an unhandled exception. Applications should
>   check the inner exception of a PingException object to identify the
>   problem.
>
> The Ping class does not throw this exception if the ICMP Echo
>   request fails because of network, ICMP, or destination errors. For
>   such errors, the Ping class returns a PingReply object with the
>   relevant IPStatus value set in the Status property.

Find more information about the PingException [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Please enter an asset tag number.", "Dramatic failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
    else
    {
        string assetTag = textBox1.Text;

        Ping pingSender = new Ping();

        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        int timeout = 1000;

        PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);

        try
        {            
            PingReply reply = pingSender.Send("WES0" + assetTag);

            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The IP address is: ", "Great sucess!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error on ping!", "Error on ping!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error on ping:" + ex.Message, "Error on ping!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
}
```